# Numerical artefacts in solution of spherical heat equation using FDM

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, diffusion, axisymmetric

I was attempting to solve the diffusion equation for a solid sphere using a naive FDM scheme. The governing PDE for the scalar concentration field $u(r,t)$ is
$$
u_t = r^{-2}(r^2 \alpha u_r)_r, \quad r \in [0,1],
$$
and is accompanied by the boundary conditions
$$
u_r(0,t) = 0, \quad u(1,t) = 0
$$
The initial condition is $u(r,1) = 1$. For simplicity $\alpha$ can be assumed to be constant.

I implemented the scheme given in the book of Langtangen and Linge (2017), [Finite Difference Computing with PDEs](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-55456-3), Springer. An exemplary Python program is given below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def sphere_fdm(t,y,r,alpha,dr):
    """Naive FDM discretization for spherically-symmetric diffusion
       
       References:
        [1] Langtangen, H. P., & Linge, S. (2017). Finite difference computing 
            with PDEs: a modern software approach. Springer Nature. (pg. 252)
    """
    n = y.shape[0]
    dydt = np.empty_like(y)

    # Symmetry condition
    dydt[0] = 6*alpha*(y[1] - y[0])/dr**2

    for i in range(1,n-1):

        rl = 0.5*(r[i] + r[i-1])
        rr = 0.5*(r[i+1] + r[i])

        gl = rl**2 * alpha * (y[i] - y[i-1])
        gr = rr**2 * alpha * (y[i+1] - y[i])

        dydt[i] = (1./r[i])**2 * (gr - gl)/dr**2

    # Dirichlet boundary
    dydt[-1] = 0

    return dydt

def sphere_sol(t,r,alpha,nterms=40):
    """Series solution of heat equation with Dirichlet boundaries

       References:
        [1] Crank, J. (1979). The Mathematics of Diffusion. 
            Oxford University Press. (pg. 91)
    """
    a_ = 1
    C = np.zeros_like(r)
    csum = 0
    for n in range(1,nterms+1):
        expterm = np.exp(-alpha*n**2*np.pi**2*t/a_**2)
        C[1:] += (-1)**n/n * np.sin(n*np.pi*r[1:]/a_) * expterm
        csum += (-1)**n * expterm

    C[1:] *= 2*a_/(np.pi*r[1:])
    C[0] = 2*csum

    C += 1
    return 1 - C

def main():

    N = 41
    r, dr = np.linspace(0,1,N,retstep=True)

    t = 0.1
    alpha = 0.1
    method="RK45"

    y = np.ones(N)
    y[-1] = 0

    rhs = lambda t, y: sphere_fdm(t,y,r,alpha,dr)
    sol = solve_ivp(rhs,[0,t],y,method=method)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    iax = ax.inset_axes([0.1,0.2,0.5,0.5])

    ax.plot(r,sol.y)
    ax.plot(r,sphere_sol(t,r,alpha),'o')

    ax.set_xlabel("r")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y(r,t)")

    iax.plot(r,sol.y)
    iax.set_xlim(0,3*dr)
    iax.set_ylim(0.98,1.02)
    iax.set_xlabel("r")

    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the solution in time, the method of lines (MOL) is used with the solvers from [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html).

While the solution agrees fairly well with the analytical solution (the red dots), when using the `"RK45"` integrator, the solution develops an unexpected kink at the center:
[image: Spherical diffusion with RK45]

The kink is not observable when I use the `"BDF"` method:
[image: Spherical diffusion with BDF]

Is there any explanation for this behavior (and assuming it's not an error in my discretized equations or Python code)?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening temporally. Does the kink develop over time or does it occur at early time then go away?

Comment: The kink appears gradually in the penetration period (short diffusion times) and then slowly disappears in the long-term regime. I suspect it may be an artefact from the jump in the initial condition, exacerbated by the singularity near the origin. Langtangen mentions that [Rannacher time-stepping](http://hplgit.github.io/fdm-book/doc/pub/book/sphinx/._book011.html#exercise-3-6-stabilizing-the-crank-nicolson-method-by-rannacher-time-stepping) can eliminate such problems, similar to the `"BDF"` method in my case. Other threads on SE suggest implicit methods being more suited to parabolic PDEs.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply change

```py
def sphere_fdm(t,y,r,alpha,dr):
    
    # Symmetry condition
    dydt[0] = 6*alpha*(y[1] - y[0])/dr**2

    # Loop
    for i in range(1,n-1):
       ...

    # Dirichlet boundary
    dydt[-1] = 0

def main():

    y = np.ones(N)
    y[-1] = 0
```

to

```py
def sphere_fdm(t,y,r,alpha,dr):

    # Loop
    for i in range(1,n-1):
       ...

    # Symmetry condition
    dydt[0] = dydt[1]

    # Dirichlet boundary
    dydt[-1] = 0

def main():

    y = np.ones(N)
    y[0]  = y[1]
    y[-1] = 0
```

**RK45**

[image: RK45]

**BDF**

[image: BDF]